# JSON parse doesn't work for ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat

So I'm using Ionic, angular, and ngCordova.  I'm trying to load a JSON file which I have saved via JSON.stringify() of an array of objects.  I have a factory that holds this array of objects, and basically I have a home page route that ng-repeats through the array to display the objects.

The loading works fine, and theoretically so does the parser; my html looks like this:

```
<ion-content ng-controller="HomePageControl">
{{posts}}
<ul class="list" ng-repeat="post in posts | limitTo:25">
  <a nav-direction="forward" class="item" ui-sref="entry({postID:$index})">
    {{post.text}}
  </a>
</ul>
<button class="button" ng-click="update()">Update</button>
```

So the "posts" is my $scope.posts object; you can see I load it before the list and during the list (I'm working on Android and this is basically the only way I can debug).  I also have a button that "updates" (reloads json and sets posts equal to the posts in the factory) the data.

My HomePageControl looks like this:

```
.controller('HomePageControl', function($scope, postsFactory){
postsFactory.updatePosts();
  $scope.posts=[];
  postsFactory.readPosts().then(function(data) {
    $scope.posts = postsFactory.getPosts();
  })
  $scope.update=function(){
    postsFactory.updatePosts();
    $scope.posts= postsFactory.getPosts();
  }


})
```

So, the problem here is that the {{posts}} spits out the correct parsed object, looking like this, except in text:

```
[{"text":"mreow"},{"text":"text"},{"text":"WORK"}]
```

But the ng-repeat DOESN'T DO ANYTHING.  It's just blank.
However, when I press the Update button a couple times, it THEN comes up with the list, but without any change in the text.  It's all basically the same code in the postsFactory too.

postsFactory:

```
.factory('postsFactory', function($cordovaFile,$ionicPlatform,$ionicPopup){
  var posts = [];
  var factory = {};
  factory.getPosts=function(){
    return posts;
  }
  factory.readPosts=function(){
      return $ionicPlatform.ready(function(){}).then(function(first){
        return $cordovaFile.readAsText(cordova.file.externalDataDirectory, "posts.json");
      }, function(error){
        return error + "not ready";
      }).then(function (second) {
          posts=JSON.parse(second);

         return posts;
      },function(error){
        return error + "Error reading";
      });
  }

  factory.updatePosts=function(){
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
      $cordovaFile.readAsText(cordova.file.externalDataDirectory, "posts.json")
       .then(function (success) {
          posts=JSON.parse(success);
       }, function (error) {
         var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: 'Error',
            template: 'Could not read file'
          });
       });
   });
  }
  return factory;
})
```

tldr; my parse works but ng-repeat isn't taking it.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some further experimentation, I found the root of the problem: it wasn't reading the JSON correctly, because it wasn't being written correctly.  I found this by replacing the JSON text, and everything loaded up fine.  So, to fix this, I used the `angular.toJson(object)` method in replacement of the `JSON.stringify(object)` function.

So, for those with the same problem, my saving script looks like this:

```
factory.newPost=function(post){
      posts.push(post);
      $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
          $cordovaFile.writeFile(cordova.file.externalDataDirectory, "posts.json", angular.toJson(posts), true).then(function (success) {

          });
      });
    }
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

As you are dealing with the asynchronous method, which is doing some asynchronous operation and returning a promise object back to the consumer function. Basically you need to put `.then` function of `getPosts` service method call. So that once data returned from the `getPosts` method it will call the success/error/catch function of the your `.then` depends on promise object `resolved/reject/error occured while processing request`

```
postsFactory.getPosts().then(function(posts){
   $scope.posts = posts;
})
```

Comment: That's what's supposed to work; I tried that the first time, but still, the problem continues.  There's no problem getting the object, as when I say "posts= [{text:"text"},{text:"text"}] right after I read the JSON, it functions correctly; it's just reading the JSON at that moment which is problematic.  It doesn't return any errors either...